# ListBoxItemSelected event not firing C# Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listboxitems i want that when i select value then page redirect to other page.I use onSelectedIndex property event function but it's not working.I search on google alot i find many solutions like autopostback property='true'. I apply all solutions but still not working.My listbox values coming from database and it load fine but page not redirecting to other page.
Here is my code aspx code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
<div class="select-db">
<form runat="server"></form>
<label style="position:relative; font-weight:bold;bottom:230px; left:450px; color:White;">Select Database</label>
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="202px" Width="262px" 
style="margin-left: 247px; margin-top: 68px" 
onselectedindexchanged="ListBox_Changed" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="True" >
</asp:ListBox>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

and here is my aspx.cs code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  getdata();
}
}
public void getdata()
{
 string user = Session["name"].ToString();
 SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HAMEED_KHAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_compiler;Integrated Security=True");
 SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT User_ID from tbl_user WHERE User_Name='" + user + "'", cnn);
 cnn.Open();
 string id = cmd2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
 int ID = Int32.Parse(id);
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USE db_compiler SELECT Database_Name FROM  Create_db WHERE User_ID='" + ID + "'", cnn);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 da.Fill(dt);
 if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   string value = row["Database_Name"] + "";
   ListBox1.Items.Add(value);
}
}
}
public void ListBox_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Session["value"] = ListBox1.SelectedValue; 
 Response.Redirect("CreateTable.aspx");
}
 public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
 //base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
}
}
```

I also use 'breakpoint' to check that event is firing or not but event is not firing.I don't know why?????

Comment: Listbox is a class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx)... so that may be confusing it. Perhaps rename the Method and the to be ListBox_Changed - remember to update your aspx page too.

Comment: I try it.I changed the name also but still not working.Now i update my question too

Comment: Are you sure that page inherits from the right class? Common problem when copy paste pages and controls.

Comment: Is the event written correctly on your original code? At least on the snippet here it's `onselectedindexchanged="ListBox_Changed"`, but asp.net is case-sensitive, and the event should be `OnSelectedIndexChanged`.

Comment: @shadow yes it inherit from master page.

Comment: @Sami Soory to say but it's not working

Comment: Does it postback when you click on an item on the listbox?

Comment: @Sami yes it post back but page not redirect to other same page again come.Actually event not firing i check it using breakpoint

Comment: It's possible that viewstate is messing it up. Set `EnableViewState="false"` on the listview.

Comment: @Sami It's not working when i set `EnableViewState="false" ` then when i select value then page postback and again same page come but listbox is empty

Comment: Is the code snippet you posted exactly like the one you have? Your `<form>` tag is closing too early. The `<ListBox>` is not inside the form. I tested the code and otherwise it runs perfectly.

Comment: @Sami yes code is this and i try again .I create new file and copy this code but still not working.

Comment: @Sami you have teamviewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All asp.net controls have to be inside a `<form>` that has a `runat="server"` attribute. Move the closing tag of your form to the end of the content and it should work. Like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
    <div class="select-db">
        <form runat="server">
            <label style="position:relative; font-weight:bold;bottom:230px; left:450px; color:White;">Select Database</label>
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="202px" Width="262px" style="margin-left: 247px; margin-top: 68px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox_Changed" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="True" >
            </asp:ListBox>
        </form>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Also remember you can only have one `<form>` with `runat="server"`.